# c# extract zip file with directory

Tags: c#, zip

I'm using c# fw4.5.
I have a simple code extracting a zip file.

```
foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in z.entries) //z is a zip file open in ZipArchiveMode.Read
{
        entry.ExtractToFile(entry.FullName);
}
```

The zip file have a directory inside it and all files are inside that directory.
When I look at the z.Entries I see its an array which place [0] is only the directory and [1],[2],[3] are files.
But when its try to do:

entry.ExtractToFile(entry.FullName);

On the first entry, I get an error:
"The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect".

I can't seems to find out whats wrong. Do I need to anything also for it to open the directory? Maybe because the entry is a directory only the "ExtractToFile(entry.FullName)" can't work?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: When you run that, what is the value of entry.FullName?  My guess is that it's either an invliad absolute path, or it unrolls to an invalid relative path.  Per the documentation on ZipArchiveEntry.ExtractToFile(), "The path is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory."

Answer (score 2):

According to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh485718(v=VS.110).aspx), the `ExtractToFile` method expects a path to a file (with an extension) and will throw an `ArgumentException` if a directory is specified.

Since the first entry in the archive is a directory and you are using its name as the argument, that is why you are having this issue.

Look into the related `ExtractToDirectory` method, which is used like so:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(@"c:\zip\archive.zip", @"c:\extract\");
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tonkleton's answer I would suggest that you use a third-party compression library since ZipArchive is not supported for framework versions before the .Net 4.5 framework, might I suggest [DotNetZip](http://DotNetZip.codeplex.com/) as mentioned in other questions regarding compression in earlier frameworks on StackOverflow.

Comment: Is this relevant when he says: "I'm using c# fw4.5."? Please let us know if you think so.

Answer (score -1):

Replace your paths:

```
void Main()
{
    var zipPath = @"\\ai-vmdc1\RedirectedFolders\jlambert\Downloads\cscie33chap1and2.zip";
    var  extractPath = @"c:\Temp\extract";

    using (ZipArchive z = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
    {
        foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in z.Entries) //z is a zip file open in ZipArchiveMode.Read
        {
            entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName), true);
        }
    } 
}
```